# Understanding unique vs multiple membership(s) (using Webform)

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

I am extensively testing CiviMember because I have several Organizations which have different membership types with different duration types.

Memberships will be managed from the Organizations (not from Individuals)

I intend to create memberships via Webforms (Contact1 = Organization ; Contact2 = Individual ; One membership for Contact2)

When I use the same Webform again for the same `Organization, Individual` pair, in certain cases it creates a new (duplicate) membership, in others, it modifies the existing one.

I'd like to understand why and when each case happens (I may be interrested by each, but need to control when)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Jacques-Marie i am not sure i follow the scenario here? When you create a Membership Type you specify the Membership Organization - therefore you would not need the Organisation on the form. If you are using 'Inherited Memberships' then you do. So which are you doing, and have you considered the former if that isn't the current usage?

Comment: Hi Pete, Thank you for your quick answer. Actually, I did not realize that before, but you are right : no need to precise the Organization, since it is derived from the Membership Type. I will test to be sure, and see if my question remains actual. I'll comme back to you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Membership Type you specify the Membership Organization - therefore you would not need the Organisation on the form if that is how you are approaching this.

If you are using 'Inherited Memberships' then you would need the Org on th form.

Based on your comment you are doing the former so I have converted this to an answer.

Comment: Thanks again Pete ; Do you mean that, if I re-submit a membership (for a same individual) : for a same membership type, the former one will be replaced, but for a different membership type, the new one will be added, even if both membership types pertain to the same Organization ?

Comment: Memberships can be complex and hopefully you have already tried https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/introduction-to-memberships/. Civi treats a membership as 'continuous' in the sense that if i join in 2010, and renew in 2011 and again in 2012 there will only be one Membership record on my account. with a Join Date back in 2010. Not sure if that is the question you are asking though

Comment: Thanks again Pete : I understand the renewal of a membership ; but what if I want to manage (for a same individual) 2 simutaneous memberships (with 2 different membership types, durations, and renewal dates), using webforms.

Comment: I don't think either civi core or Webform-CiviCRM will support 2 memberships in same transaction. To do that I would integrate Commerce which is a much more demanding process. Doing so would allow you to add any number of memberships in to your cart and then buy them in one go.

Comment: Hi Pete, could you have a look to the following question (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/duplicate-memberships), which may explain why I don't clearly understand this feature. FYI, I use a simple Webform with a single membership and no contribution (member dues).

Answer (score 3):

The Webform integration determines whether to add or update a membership based on the "Membership Organization" of the membership type. Say you have the following membership types defined:

- **Organization: Soccer Club**

  *Membership Types:*

  1. Youth soccer
  2. Teen soccer
  3. Adult soccer
- **Organization: Tennis Club**

  *Membership Types:*

  1. Youth tennis
  2. Teen tennis
  3. Adult tennis

Now say you have signed up a person for a "Youth soccer" membership. If you subsequently sign them up for a "Teen soccer" membership, Webform will detect that you are upgrading membership within the same organization and it will bump their existing membership from youth to teen. If however you sign them up for a "Teen tennis", it will leave their soccer membership alone, and add the tennis additionally.

Comment: Thank you Coleman, you make it very clear. In conclusion, I was wrong making Contact 1 as Organisation and Contact 2 as Individual : there is only one Contact (Individual), who can have one or several memberships (of one or several Organisation(s))

Comment: @Jacques-MarieMoranne please upvote & accept this answer :)