# Duplicate Memberships

Tags: civimember

As per the documentation (https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/defining-memberships/) :

"If you wish to enable online sign ups or renewals, the CiviCRM data model requires that a contact can only have one active membership with a single organisation at any given time. "

I currently have 2 CiviCRMs/Drupal : one in production, and one for tests (both in 7.44/4.7.6), and I use Webform to create the memberships.

The test Civi does not actually create duplicate memberships : each new membership replaces the previous one : which is in accordance, and correct.

But the production CiviCRM creates duplicate memberships :
[image: Screen Copy]

How can this happen ?
Is this connected with "If you wish to enable online sign ups or renewals" ?
How can I change that ?

Comment: please confirm whether you have the same rules in both production and testing server - Contacts -> Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. I use the same dedupe rules on both servers, and I have no duplicate contact (the contact is not duplicated, only memberships are).

Comment: J-M - before I try and answer the actual question can you explain why i am not seeing End Dates? Are these Lifetime memberships?

Comment: Actually, those are Lifetime memberships. Is there a different behaviour between Lifetime and Fixed Memberships ? BTW, when I want to create a duplicate lifetime membership on the test server, I get the following message (not the case with de production server) : Notice : Undefined index: end_date dans wf_crm_webform_postprocess->processMemberships() (ligne 1102 dans /home/paroisse/public_html/test/drupal/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc).